# Get user type in Joomla with PHP

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

I'm trying to get a logged in users type (eg super admin, registered). I've tried this code:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$curref = $user->usertype();
```

Which gives a function not found error. What is the correct way to get the user type name, without a db query if possible.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Hi, just been trying it out, commented on your answer and accepted it as the answer. Would appreciate any help you can give on the comment I've left though, thanks.

Comment: The usertype attribute is deprecated in joomla 2.5 and hence should no longer be used. It may be working for you because you migrated from 1.5, but new users won't have it set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to treat usertype as a member, not a method.

```
$type = $user->usertype;
```

Documentation: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object

You can take a look at the $user object structure by doing a var_dump. Try this, and inspect the output:

```
var_dump( $user );
```

So if you want to iterate over the groups array, you could do the following:

```
$groupIDs = array();
foreach( $user->groups as $groupID ){
  $groupIDs[] = $groupID;
}

var_dump( $groupIDs );
```

You can also use some joomla methods to return the groups in different ways. You may want to check out this forum thread: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=530721

Comment: Thank you for the reply any advice. I had actually read that page for this, but as you said I had referenced it wrong. Turns out I will need to use the group codes instead as the user types I am looking for are on a second level/child. So I need to get the info from this output/group id `["groups"]=> array(1) { [9]=> string(1) "9" }`. To get the 9 in this case, I'd need `$type=$user->groups[9];` however I won't know this as it will vary for each user. Any ideas how I can access this value dynamically?